# how to find the permutations and combinations of any integer value?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I want to get permutations and combinations in Objective C.I have found both but their is some problem in my code that I don't understand where is it occurring. Actually I want to print the value in a textfield but it prints the last value I entered. I used the code as given below. help me anyone please..

```
    typedef enum{Power,Exponent,nCr,nPr} CalcOperation;
    NSString *storage;
    CalcOperation operation;
   -(IBAction)combination{ 
    operation = nPr; 
    storage = label.text;
    textField.text=@"";
    label.text = @"";
    }

   -(int) factorial:(int)n{
   int d = n;
   int temp = 1;
   for(int b = 2; b <= d; b++){
    temp = temp*b;
   }
  //NSLog(@"the factorials is = %i",temp);

  return temp;
 }

 -(IBAction)equalButton{
  float tempo = [storage floatValue];
  float b = [label.text floatValue];
  NSString *val = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f" , b];  

    switch(operation) {
     case nCr:

     textField.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",[self factorial:tempo] / ([self factorial:[val floatValue]] * [self factorial:tempo-[val floatValue]])]; 
            //textField.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",[val floatValue]+tempo+10];
          NSLog(@"combination %d",[self factorial:tempo] / ([self factorial:[val floatValue]] * [self factorial:tempo-[val floatValue]]));
            break;
    case nPr:

            textField.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%f",[self factorial:tempo] / [self factorial:tempo-[val floatValue]]]; 
           NSLog(@"permutations %d",[self factorial:tempo] / ([self factorial:tempo-[val floatValue]]));
            break;  `
                  }
                }
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Try setting breakpoints and stepping through your code.

Comment: yes many time it cal the factorial method and find the factorial but can not combine the result and print the last value that i have enter in the textfield.

Comment: Try making you `factorial:` method return a `float` instead of an `int` maybe? Also, try log gin each of the individual values as well as their combination to see if you are at least getting the values right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//to calculate nCr where n = tempo, r = b

```
int tempo = [storage intValue];
int b = [label.text intValue];

float tempCb =  (float)[self factorial:tempo] / ([self factorial:b] * [self factorial:tempo-b])]; 

            break;
```

Comment: textField.text = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%d",[self factorial:tempo] / ([self factorial:[val floatValue]] * [self factorial:tempo-[val floatValue]])]; // ur method is also right but i have correct it just change %f to %d in my code

Comment: You use float for factorial storage. But facorials is for numbers, and the result should be a number.